# Passing array in HTML form with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to use Jquery to pass an array to an HTML form as follows:

```
$('form#'+ID1+' input#myArray').val(theArray);
```

Then my form is as follows

```
<input type="hidden" id="myArray" name="myArray">
```

I then serialize before calling an Ajax request:

```
var dataString=$('form#grid1').serialize();
```

But on the receiving script I get:

```
Uninitialized string offset: 1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show more code. This isn't helpful.

Comment: this makes no sense. please provide... i dont even know what i would want you to provide... more code

Comment: 'grid1' is the id of the form

Comment: then what is form# + ID1 + ?

Comment: Sorry it should be: $('form#'+grid1+' input#myArray').val(theArray);

Comment: BTW If I use Firebug to check the data I can see that the array is being passed, the data seems to be encoded with % signs

Comment: Also the array I am trying to pass is an array of array, is that possible?

Comment: If you see `%2C` in the encoded value, that is a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best guess from what you are showing in the question.

When you call the following, the array represented by `theArray` is converted into a comma-separated string and placed in the hidden input element. This is the case even if `theArray` is a nested array.

```
$('form#'+ID1+' input#myArray').val(theArray);
```

But on the server, you are trying to treat the posted "myArray" value as an array, so you get the following error:

```
Uninitialized string offset: 1
```

The problem is that "myArray" is not an array, but is a comma-separated string.

I recommend formatting the `theArray` value as JSON before setting it into the hidden input element, especially if it is a nested array. You can do this:

```
$('form#'+ID1+' input#myArray').val(JSON.stringify(theArray));
```

Then parse it to an object on the server side. I'm guessing from the error message that you are using PHP, so you would do something like this:

```
$myArray = json_decode($_POST['myArray']);
```

Comment: John S - you are the absolute Daddy. I bow before you, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you!!!

Comment: @user2056238 - I see you have asked 13 questions, but have never accepted an answer. If an answer solves your problem, you should check it as accepted. You can also up-vote an answer if it helps.

Comment: sorry, i'm quite new to this... where is the link to accept an answer?

Comment: I found it, just went back and clicked on 'answered' for previous questions. Thanks!